# Converting scripts to a different version of Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have some Python scripts written with Python 2.7. I have to use that scripts with Python 3.x, but I have to change so many things like:

```
print "something"
```

to

```
print ("something")
```

because Python 3.x doesn't support *print* function without parenthesis. I don't want to do that  manually because it will be too long and hard. I tried *re* module but failed. I am stuck, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: 2to3 is a Python program that reads Python 2.x source code and applies a series of fixers to transform it into valid Python 3.x https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html

Comment: Im new Im sorry if this question is low quality...

Comment: its ok but its better that at least have a search before asking a question !

Comment: Kasra I really search it I cant find and ask here..

Comment: Then you are bad at searching: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1777767/3001761

Comment: you had a bad search if you have been searched for run python 2 source with python 3 surely you should find meany reference

Comment: My english is not good sorry.. Then I fail when I search

Comment: In 2.x, `print('something')` (with only one item between `(` and `)`) does exactly the same thing as `print something`.  The parentheses are ignored.  So you can easily make prints work in both 2.x and 3.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
import re                 

with open("myprogram.py","r",encoding='utf8') as f:
    for x in f.readlines():
        y = x   # Main code x defining as y.
        if re.findall("print",x) == ['print']: # if 'print' is found;
            x = "print(" + x.split("print")[1].strip() + ")" # strip it quotation mark and paranthesis;
            y = y.replace(y,x)  #.. replace y with x.
        with open("different.py","a+") as ff:
            (y.strip()) # attention using \n for every sentence..
```

But it may break your code's design. So print them and copy-paste.

```
import re                 

with open("myprogram.py","r",encoding='utf8') as f:
    for x in f.readlines():
        y = x   # Main code x defining as y.
        if re.findall("print",x) == ['print']: # if 'print' is found;
            x = "print(" + x.split("print")[1].strip() + ")" # strip it quotation mark and paranthesis;
            y = y.replace(y,x)  #.. replace y with x.
        print(y.strip())
```

Comment: wow this is working. Im trying to understand x and strip part.

Comment: This is not a great idea. What if the word `print` appears in contexts other than as a statement (variable names, string literals, etc.)? It also doesn't handle e.g. the trailing comma bring replaced with the keyword argument `end=''`.

Comment: thankyou for answer It helped really thanks Im new in python sorry if this question is silly....

Comment: @whatwasthat why have you accepted this answer? It does not cover many of the common edge cases for `print` (or any of the other changes between 2.x and 3.x) and is not well implemented.

Comment: @jonrsharpe *why have you accepted this answer?* ... Now you know :/

Answer (score 4):

Try the automated `2to3` library

https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html

```
$ 2to3 example.py
```

To make the changes directly

```
$ 2to3 -w example.py
```

**STEPS**

1. Write your code in a file called example.py

   `print "something"`
2. Save and close. Open a terminal and type

   `2to3 -w example.py`
3. Open the file now. Tada ... the code is converted

   `print(something)`

Comment: It one is going to run an automated conversion program, this is better, more general, and tested answer.  The lib2to3 doc explains the use of the 2to3.py script.  I have used it to convert a medium-sized package of multiple modules.